# Date changing to US Format in Angular during Validation

Tags: angularjs, date

I am doing some validation in angular where date added by user has to be greater than some other date on form.

On dateChange on input:From, i call this method which check for validation but when i try to get the date entered, it get date in US version.

ex:
`var from = new Date(viewValue);`

viewvalue is "08/04/2016" but **from** comes out as 'Thu Aug 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)'

What can i do so that **from** comes out as April 8th ?

Thanks.

Comment: you could use `date` filter with `format` option provided to it, if its just used for display purpose.

Comment: @PankajParkar: Display works ok without any problem. I am struck at validation where viewValue get passed as what user has entered (08/04/2016) and is correct but `var from` converts that in US format date and it messes up the validation as my date is in dd/mm/yyyy version.

Comment: `from` is coming out that way in your console, because that's the default format of `Date.prototype.toString`, not because it's stored that way. If you type `from.valueOf()` it will give you a big number, representing the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. You should not use `new Date()` for string validation; instead use a regular expression, or use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Momentjs:

http://momentjs.com

[Momentjs Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
var from = new Date(viewValue);
var date = moment(from).format('MMM Do');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wdsypae/)